# htaccess redirection with querystring

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect the following url
http://test.com/changefile.php?filename=top-ranked-colleges

to

http://test.com/top-ranked-colleges.php
using htaccess redirection.

Anybody please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filename=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://test.com/%1.php? [R=301,L]
```

to change  `http://test.com/changefile.php?filename=top-ranked-colleges` to `http://test.com/top-ranked-colleges.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).php$
RewriteRule .* http://test.com/changefile.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

to change `http://test.com/top-ranked-colleges.php` to `http://test.com/changefile.php?filename=top-ranked-colleges`

Answer (score 1):

This **does** work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/changefile\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filename=([0-9a-z_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/%1.php? [R=301,L]
```

#### Explanation

`%1` comes from: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filename=**([0-9a-z_-]+)**$

Have a `?` on the RewriteRule stops the original query string being added to the redirect

If the file being called is changefile.php, and it has a querystring with filename= within it, then redirect using `%1` as the page to go to.

If you use RewriteBase, you will need to add this in too:

e.g:

```
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/test/changefile\.php$
```

This **doesn't** work:

```
RewriteRule ^changefile.php?filename=([a-z0-9-]+)$ http://test.com/$1.php? [R=301,L]
```

This is due to the fact you cannot check the querystring with `RewriteRule` or `RedirectMatch`

Comment: is it necessary to give RewriteCond

Comment: I used ur code. but the url is as http://test.com/changefile.php?filename=top-ranked-colleges

Comment: You right weird, I've used something like this before. I'll double check it.