# How to redirect a URL with a querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've moved a website to a new domain and I've used `RewriteRule` to redirect a number of my URLs.

**I'm stuck** trying to redirect URLs with query strings in them?

```
RewriteRule  /news/archive.php?cat=economic-impact http://www.new-website.com/faqs/economic-impact [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /news/archive.php?cat=housing-need http://www.new-website.com/faqs/housing-need R=301,L]
RewriteRule /news/archive.php?cat=infrastructure http://www.new-website.com/faqs/infrastructure R=301,L]
```

Further up the `htaccess` file I'm using this to redirect the domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-website.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-website.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new-website.com/$1 [R=301]
```

When I visit:

```
old-website.com/news/archive.php?cat=economic-impact
```

it redirects to

```
new-website.com/news/archive.php?cat=economic-impact
```

Which 404s, I need to to redirect to:

```
new-website.com/faqs/economic-impact
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you need it only for these strings  3 above or you want `/news/archive.php?cat=anything` redirected to `http://www.new-website.com/faqs/anything`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirection with querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383574/htaccess-redirection-with-querystring)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a blank query string on your rewrite to truncate any existing query strings.

The below should do the job:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new-website.com/$1? [R=301]
```

In addition, the way you're checking the existing query strings won't work. You'll need to check them separately:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "cat=(economic-impact|housing-need|infrasructure)"
RewriteRule news/archive.php http://www.new-website.com/faqs/%1? R=301,L]
```

The `%1` will take a backreference from a regex group match in the `RewriteCond`

Comment: Without `/` in the beginning of RewriteRule htaccess uri: `RewriteRule news/archive.php http://www.new-website.com/faqs/%1? [R=301,L]`